# QuickTime X can't use .srt files

Tags: quicktime, subtitle

For some reason, ever since Apple released QuickTime X, QuickTime won't open files with an associated .srt file anymore. I get the error QuickTime can't open it and if I would like to open it in QuickTime 7. And the strange part is, the .srt files are working with Preview.
I have Perian installed correctly.

I don't mind using QuickTime 7 and I know VLC is far better in using .srt files, but still. This question intrigues me a lot.

How can I make QuickTime X work with .srt files?

Comment: Do you have Perian installed? As far as I am aware you need Perian for it to work, but I haven't got a setup with me at the moment to confirm?

Comment: Yes I have Perian installed.

Comment: try uninstalling and reinstalling Perian.  Reading the Perian mailing list, there were some issues with machines upgraded to Lion that already had Perian installed.

Comment: I'll try when i get the chance! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 6):

I strongly recommend [Subler](https://bitbucket.org/galad87/subler/downloads), with which you can not only soft bake the subtitles but easily add metadata as well. This allows playback with subtitles on iTunes and iOS devices as well, and even swiftly converts .mkv files for playback on these devices as well.

Small tutorial:

1. Drag a movie file on `Subler`, then drag the .srt-file on the newly opened window
2. Optionally choose a language and set as default to autoload
3. Optionally click the search icon on the top right to add metadata
4. Click the share icon right next to the search icon to merge the files

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put the SRT subtitles to a subtitle track in movies. Quicktime Player X supports multiple language of subtitles and chapters as well. Subtitle Writer on Mac App Store might be a good tool for this.