# SRT subtitle problem

Tags: quicktime, subtitle

I have the same issue as in [this question][1], but now, there is no Perian to help me out. I have an m4v film that I can play in QT7 and see the subtitles, but not in QTX.

I've tried Subler, Handbrake and Submerge. I've tried QT7 export, and VLC.

I really want to get the film into iTunes. Does anyone know some methods?

UPDATE - thanks to Kerlix. I had to save the art in UTF-8.

```
This was the sequence that worked for me:

Handbrake from avi to m4v
Subler:

 - . remove any existing subtitles 
Save and verify 
Convert my subtitles to UTF-8 Subler  

. new file 
. drag in movie 
. import my subtitles. 
. at first import screen, change Passthrough to Tx3g 
. OK 
. change default language to your subtitle language 
. save 
Test in QTX

  [1]: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/quicktime-x-cant-use-srt-files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might try Subs Factory or re-saving the SRT in Text Wrangler as UTF-8. Or re-encoding the file with the SRT as soft subs in Handbrake. I've also used MPEGStreamclip and Avidemux for other file formats. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. Saving the SRT in UTF-8 format (I did it in TextMate), solved the problem. I have updated my question with the sequence that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Subtitle Writer to save your SRT subtitles to m4v on Mac. If you want to edit or create a SRT subtitles on mac, SRT Edit Pro is a good choice. These 2 app on Mac App Store are made by me. Try it, if you have any concern, email me.

Comment: Thanks for disclosing your relationship with the product. Welcome to Ask Different!